# Perform SSH remote cmd exec on multiple local servers from input (sshpass?)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, networking

I am currently looking for a solution for executing remote commands on multiple local servers from an input file containing the 'user : password' in the following format:

```
jboss5:manager:192.168.1.101
database1:db01:192.168.20.6
server8:localnet:192.168.31.83
x:z:192.168.1.151
test:mynet:192.168.35.44
.... and others
```

Some commands I wish to execute remotely:

```
cd $HOME; ./start_script.sh; wget 192.168.1.110/monitor.sh; chmod +x monitor.sh; ./monitor.sh
```

I know there is a utility called "sshpass" but not sure how I could apply this utility for my needs.

Comment: Just parse the file line by line and use the given variables: `sshpass -p password user@ip-address "commands-to-execute"`

Answer (score 0):

```
Yes sshpass is a good option, you can use it as below

    sshpass -p "pass_here" ssh user@ip "cd $HOME; exit" #password is provided on the command line with semi-colon separated commands

Note: you need to install sshpass before you use it, it can be install using simple command as below,

    apt-get install sshpass
```